# trying to close dialog box on google chrome but after refresh it comes back

Tags: popup

On my Amazon Seller Central page under Manage Orders tab it gives me 2 options Easy Ship and Self ship and it gives a dialog box to click next then click next and a check box to click close and dont show this again but after i refresh the page the close box comes up again.

Can anyone guide me how to fix the issue?

I tried clearing cache from google chrome, tried running the page on mozilla firefox but still the same issue